# Discord.py- How to make bot send a message when pinged but not when replied to

Tags: python, discord.py

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DauxG.png) I'm trying to make something where if the bot is pinged it says a message like "For a list of commands, type .help" and my code works except for it also says that when the bot is replied to.

This is my code - Using discord.py 1.7.3

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message) and message.mention_everyone is False:
        await message.channel.send("For a list of commands, type `.help`")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `client.user.mention`. You can also check `if client.user.mention in message.content` if you want to know whether the bot is mentioned somewhere in the message rather than checking if the mention comprises the entire message.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mention == message.content and message.mention_everyone is False:
        await message.channel.send("For a list of commands, type `.help`")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

**Reference**:

- [*abstractmethod* mention](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=mention#discord.abc.User.mention)